# Error while using always block for half adder: sum is not a valid l-value

Tags: verilog

```
module halfadder(a,B,sum,carry);
input a,B;
output sum,carry;
always@(a,B)
  begin
     sum=a^B;
     carry=a&B;
  end
endmodule
```

For the above code, I am getting error:

```
: sum is not a valid l-value in tb_halfadder.ha.
: sum is declared here as wire.
: carry is not a valid l-value in tb_halfadder.ha.
: carry is declared here as wire.
```

Comment: Anyway, your `always` is not really necessary. Your sensitivity list is `a,B`. Your assignments are `a^B` and `a&B`. The definition of `assign` is that the value of the RHS is calculated and assigned to the LHS **whenever any of the RHS operands change**. So simple assignments will work here just the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum` and `carry` are not valid l-values because they are driven in a `always` block. They should be declared as `reg`.

```
reg sum, carry;
```

When a port is not declared with a type, it automatically gets a type of `wire`.

Comment: Or leave them as wires, but use `assign` and not `always`.

Comment: Well, `output reg sum, carry;` to be annoyingly technical...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I use this syntax only: `module halfadder(input a, ...`, for years. So I'm not sure if I can combine `output` and `reg` in the same line, if ports are declared outside that `()`.

Comment: Well, I actually also use that syntax so now you made me wonder LOL

Comment: Actually declaring them as reg worked! Thank you :)